# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.Fragment.setArguments(android.os.Bundle)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, tabs, bundle

In my Activity A, it has a listView. When the listView is clicked, it will pass the **ID** to Activity B which use the adapter to display the data corresponding to the tab selected.

**Activity A**

```
 listViewEdit.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding listview_item_row in the result set
                Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                // Get the state's capital from this listview_item_row in the database.
                 ID =
                        cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityB.class);
                intent.putExtra("ID",ID);
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });
    }
```

**Activity B**

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);
        id=getIntent().getExtras().getString("ID");
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        tabsAdapter = new TabsFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(tabsAdapter);
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(item[i]).setTabListener(this));
        }
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int arg) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(arg);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

    }
```

**TabsFragmentPagerAdapter**

```
  @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Fragment fragment=null;

        if(index == 0) {

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putLong("ID", Edit.ID);
            Log.e("ID", Edit.ID+"");
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            return new EditInformation();

        }

        if(index == 1)
            return new Edit_WorkForce();
        if(index == 2)
            return new Edit_WorkDetails();


        return null;
    }
```

**EditInformation**

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View edit_info = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_information, container, false);
        Name=(EditText)edit_info.findViewById(R.id.Edit_name);
        Status=(EditText)edit_info.findViewById(R.id.Edit_status);
        Weather=(EditText)edit_info.findViewById(R.id.Edit_weather);
        Date=(EditText)edit_info.findViewById(R.id.Edit_date);
        ts = new com.example.project.myapplication.API.InfoAPI(getActivity());
        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        if(getArguments()!=null)
        {
            ID=bundle.getLong("ID");
        }
        RetrieveInformation(ID);

        return edit_info;
    }
```

When I click the list in Activity A, app crashed and shows the error as below.

```
  Process: com.example.project.myapplication, PID: 3103
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.Fragment.setArguments(android.os.Bundle)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.project.myapplication.Adapter.TabsFragmentPagerAdapter.getItem(TabsFragmentPagerAdapter.java:35)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:97)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:870)
```

I can get the ID from Activity A and this is the line where error refer to     `fragment.setArguments(bundle);`

Comment: Look at the `getItem()` method in the Adapter. You set `Fragment fragment=null;`, then `if(index == 0)`, you're trying to set arguments on a null Fragment.

Comment: @MikeM. How do I set the argument ?

Comment: Set `fragment = new EditInformation();` before you set the arguments, then `return fragment;`.

Comment: should I remove return `new EditInformation();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **TabsFragmentPagerAdapter**, Change

```
Fragment fragment=null;
if(index == 0) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putLong("ID", Edit.ID);
    Log.e("ID", Edit.ID+"");
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return new EditInformation();
}
...
```

to

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Fragment fragment=null;
    if(index == 0) {
        fragment = new EditInformation();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putLong("ID", Edit.ID);
        Log.e("ID", Edit.ID+"");
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }
    ...
}
```

You need to **initialize** the `EditInformation` fragment before setting its arguments.

Comment: should I  remove  `return new EditInformation();` ?